# How should electron app handle a OAuth callback

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth, electron

I am pretty fresh to the electron, and I am working on building an application that uses Facebook/Google to authorize a user. Everything works fine when I am working on development, when I just use localhost:3000 as the callback URL for Facebook/Google API. But when I build the app and run it, things just fell apart. I followed the [steps on this medium post here](https://medium.com/@kitze/%EF%B8%8F-from-react-to-an-electron-app-ready-for-production-a0468ecb1da3) to configured the building proces. And to make it simple I just used the npm submodule: [react-facebook-login](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login), [react-google-login](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login).

I thoughts there should be any difference between these two, but the process works fine on dev but not on built app:

[image: authorization works good on dev][image: fell apart on built app]

Should I treat this case as a native app and rebuild the authorization from scratch instead of using node module?

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: You should additionally register callback URL for `localhost` in your  Identity Provider. I guess that you registered only URL of you production app.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#oauth2-with-installed-apps-electron This one work for me

Answer (score -1):

Part of the way OAuth2 works is that the step of getting the authorisation code invokes the login dialog you see from Facebook or Google or whatever. For your app to regain control after that dialog is done requires your request to open the dialog to specify a "redirect_url" at which your app will get back control.

Also, part of the security is that Facebook or Google or whatever will *check* the redirect_url you specify against some preconfigured settings.

Therefore:

- You have to configure the redirect URL(s) you plan to use
- You have to ensure that the redirect URL used matches one you configured

Failing either will typically result in a messae like the one you are seeing.

Comment: when an electron app is built for production, the frontend part is not served using a server, instead it is served from file system. Facebook and Google oAuth do not allow people to redirect to file system based urls, also, that file system url is different for different systems. The provided answer does not highlight what needs to be done and it is not even in the right direction IMHO.